# how to get user's last login with OneToOneField and display it on admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "/Users/rustem/studypageback/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/rustem/studypageback/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
self.check(display_num_errors=True)
File "/Users/rustem/studypageback/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 436, in check
raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
ERRORS:
<class 'portal_users.admin.ProfileAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[10]' refers to 'user__last_login', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'ProfileAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'portal_users.Profile'.
System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

There is my code

models.py:

class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(
User,
null=True,
related_name='profile',
on_delete=CUSTOM_SET_NULL,
)
student_id = models.IntegerField(
blank=True,
null=True,
verbose_name='ID студента/преподавателя',
help_text='Из 1С',
)

```
first_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=200,
    verbose_name='Имя',
    blank=True,
)
last_name = models.CharField(
    max_length=200,
    verbose_name='Фамилия',
    blank=True,
)
```

admin.py:

@admin.register(models.Profile)
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

```
list_display = [
    'user',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'user__last_login',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a custom method that would display the last login on admin:

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['user','first_name', 'last_name', 'get_last_login']
    
    def get_last_login(self,instance):
        return instance.user.last_login
    get_last_login.short_description = "Last login"
```

More on this: [Documentation on `list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display)